# Add div after each field of a certain name

Tags: entities, theming

I'm trying to display a div container after each field item with the name additional_content of my page content type. Right now im trying to preprocess my field but i can't go down to the real field item i want to proprocess...

Is it better to override the template? And how would that work? i have a field called additional_content integrated into my page content type. After this has been printed i want to add a div container to each of this items.

Any help with that?

Comment: So you want to wrap entire field content with `<div>` and `</div>`?

Comment: @user11153 no i just want to append a <div></div> Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy `modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php` file into `sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates`

Rename it to `field--additional_content--YOURCONTENTTYPENAME.tpl.php`
(or only `field--additional_content.tpl.php` if you want to change its template for all content types)

Edit its template like this:

```
<div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
    <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
    <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>
      <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>><?php print render($item); ?></div>
      <div class="your-additional-div"></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are right...its just that simple...i tried that but always foot to add the tpl. grrr